# I have a module in python 3.8 but to use it in 3.7

Tags: python, module, python-3.7, computer-science, python-3.8

I downloaded the module pyttsx3 but it did not work in 3.8 so I decided to use it in 3.7 but when I tried it in 3.7
`Module Not found error:`
was displayed. What should I do so that I can use pyttsx3 in 3.7

Comment: Install using 3.7 again

Answer (score 0):

try uninstalling and reinstalling an older version of `pyttsx3`, worked for me for python 3.7

```
pip install pyttsx3==2.71
```

also have you tried installing pypiwin32?

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have pip3.7 installed.

```
python3.7 -m pip install pip
```

Then use: `pip3.7 install pyttsx3`. You can put `alias pip='pip3.7' in your ~/.bashrc file to create an alias for the new pip.